In Excel, how to show linked cell in the first row
I have a Table of contents pointing to different cells (link example =sheet1!video) in the workbook. Each worksheet has some 500 rows of information
When the link is selected, it goes to correct cell, highlights it but if the result is in example row 250, it is showing it at the bottom of the screen.
How do I force Excel to, when the link to cell is clicked, it moves the sheet up so that the selected cell is in the first row.

Try this code in the sheet module from which the link originates.
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Goto ActiveCell, True
End Sub


This is working quite beautifully. Thank you.
